# Swiper, how to get translateX real-time?

Tags: swiper.js

I want to get translateX of `swiper-wrapper` real-time. I will use the real-time `translateX` to do some works.

```js
swiper.on('sliderMove', function onSliderMove() {
  console.log(this.getTranslate(), this.translate); //-64 -64, or maybe other value, but not -320
});
```

I listen to `sliderMove` event, but the result is not correct.

I inspect the `swiper-wrapper` element, the style is

```
transition-duration: 0ms; 
transform: translate3d(-320px, 0px, 0px);
```

I expect the value of `this.getTranslate()` should be `-320`, not `-64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listen on `setTranslate` event will work.

```js
swiper.on('setTranslate', function onSliderMove() {
  console.log(this.translate);
});
```